# Java printing on labels. Problems with MediaSize

Tags: java, printing, label

I try to print barcodes with a zebra tlp 2824 on 1.5x1" labels. This is what I did in Java:

```
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE;
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A10);        
aset.add(new Copies(1));
```

When I print it looks like this:

[image: Imgur]

So I tried to scale it a little bit down to see if it has something to do with the source-file. But it seems like the source is correctly displayed. I think it has something to do with the media size which seems to stay in portrait format so the source image is cut. I'm not sure if A10 is the right format to chose here but it has nearly the right measures for labels like I want to use. Ill appreciate some help here.

Comment: Try a MediaPrintableArea, rather than a MediaSizeName.

Comment: Im not quiet sure how to use it. `aset.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0, 0, 38, 25, MediaPrintableArea.MM));` prints me four white labels in a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this line helped:

```
aset.add(MediaSize.findMedia(2, 1, Size2DSyntax.INCH));
```